# QML: How to animate integer (not real)

Tags: animation, qml, qt-quick

My problem is that I can't animate integer.

I am showing some result as integer number in Text element, like this:

```
Text
{
 text: someResult
}
```

And I have defined behavior:

```
Behavior on text
{
 NumberAnimation{ duration: 1000; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad}
}
```

Problem is that animated text gets real numbers, and I want integers to be.

---

**Example**: previous value is 0, and I set new value as 2, this is how animation looks like:

```
0
0.01
0.05
0.1
0.156
0.36
...
1.81
1.95
2
```

But what I want to be is:

```
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by explicitly animating an integer property:

```
Text {
    property int value: 0
    text: value
    Behavior on value {
        NumberAnimation { duration: 1000; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was searching for. Thanks :)

Comment: Is this still the best way to do this is 2021? Feels like a weird workaround